# Nuclide C++ simple Buck config

Tags: c++, buck, nuclide-editor

I want to build and run C++ programs from Nuclide using Buck.
The problem is that I don't know how to setup a simple Buck configuration file in Nuclide to build and then run a `.cpp` file.

So does someone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Building a hello-world program with Buck is very easy. Create the following files in your project directory:

`.buckconfig`

(can be empty)

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello, world. " << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

`BUCK`

```
cxx_binary(
  name = 'hello-world',
  srcs = [
    'main.cpp'
  ],
)
```

Nuclide should find everything for you if you open Atom from your project folder.

To check that every works, run:

```
buck run //:hello-world
```

That should be enough to get started; further information can be found [on the Buck website](https://buckbuild.com/rule/cxx_binary.html).